# get pairwise sums of multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rowsum

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

`x<-data.frame(a=6, b=5:1, c=7, d=10:6)`

```
> x
  a b c  d
1 6 5 7 10
2 6 4 7  9
3 6 3 7  8
4 6 2 7  7
5 6 1 7  6
```

I am trying to get the sums of columns `a` & `b` and `c`&`d` in another data frame that should look like:

```
> new
  ab cd
1 11 17
2 10 16
3  9 15
4  8 14
5  7 13
```

I've tried the `rowSums()` function but it returns the sum of ALL the columns per row, and I tried `rowSums(x[c(1,2), c(3,4)])` but nothing works. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` on a column subset.

**As a data frame:**

```
data.frame(ab = rowSums(x[c("a", "b")]), cd = rowSums(x[c("c", "d")]))
#   ab cd
# 1 11 17
# 2 10 16
# 3  9 15
# 4  8 14
# 5  7 13
```

**As  a matrix:**

```
cbind(ab = rowSums(x[1:2]), cd = rowSums(x[3:4]))
```

For a wider data frame, you can also use `sapply` over a list of column subsets.

```
sapply(list(1:2, 3:4), function(y) rowSums(x[y]))
```

**For all pairwise column combinations:**

```
y <- combn(ncol(x), 2L, function(y) rowSums(x[y]))
colnames(y) <- combn(names(x), 2L, paste, collapse = "")
y
#      ab ac ad bc bd cd
# [1,] 11 13 16 12 15 17
# [2,] 10 13 15 11 13 16
# [3,]  9 13 14 10 11 15
# [4,]  8 13 13  9  9 14
# [5,]  7 13 12  8  7 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
> sapply(split.default(x, 0:(length(x)-1) %/% 2), rowSums)
      0  1
[1,] 11 17
[2,] 10 16
[3,]  9 15
[4,]  8 14
[5,]  7 13
```

The `0:(length(x)-1) %/% 2` step creates a sequence of groups of 2 that can be used with `split`. It will also handle odd numbers of columns (treating the final column as a group of its own). Since there's a different default `split` "method" for `data.frame`s that splits by rows, you need to specify `split.default` to split the columns into groups.